# JList not showing on JScrollPane

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jlist

I am making a program for a family enterprise that will manage the brochures from their raw materials providers. I find you will need all the code, so I posted it on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/Gc3aLe10

But also, here I attach where I think the problem is:

```
tnBuscar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String search = searchField.getText();
            Connection con = null;
            java.sql.Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            String db = "FAVEGA";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                st = con.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM catalogos WHERE id = '" + search + "' OR name LIKE '%" + search + "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
                rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    final String resultName = rs.getString("name");
                    buffer.add(resultName);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                btnEditar.setVisible(true);
                btnReiniciar.setVisible(true);
                final JList list = new JList(buffer.toArray());         
                final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
                scrollPane.add(list);
                scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
                scrollPane.setBounds(67, 195, 269, -143);
                buscarPanel.add(scrollPane);                    
                list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                list.setBounds(0, 0, 435, 240);

                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 80));
                list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
                buscarPanel.invalidate();
                buscarPanel.validate();
                btnEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(list.getSelectedValue() != null){
                            String selectedValue = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
                            tab.setSelectedIndex(2);
                            btnReiniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                scrollPane.setVisible(false);
                                btnEditar.setVisible(false);
                                btnReiniciar.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            });
                }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

This button searches for items in my database, but it somehow doesn't load the JList when it runs. What is the problem?
PS:No runtime errors, no Stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't re_create whole GUI,
2. use [XxxListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) instead of remove & add `JComponents` to the `JPanel`
3. all updates to the [XxxModel must be done on EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
4. right `finally` block is always fired, but not right place for creating GUI
5. have to call `revalidate()` & `repaint()` if you remove and then add `JComponent` from/to the already visible `container`

Comment: Could you please explain a bit slower? This was created by windowsBuilder and I added some changes to it. I'm quite new to Java and to programming, so can you please explain it with more detail?

Comment: @user1178729: You're creating a whole bunch of new components in that finally block, components that don't appear to be displayed anywhere. Why not simply display the information in components that are already realized on the GUI? 1+ to mKorbel of course for his great answer.

Comment: The components declared in the finally are displayed afterwards. I only find two elements declared in the finally, which are the list(which I add there because it takes the buffer variable from the rs.hasNext() event) and the scrollPane, which I think needs to be added there as it needs the list.

Comment: @user1178729: you should start using layout managers as absolute positioning is risky for causing bugs, and is very hard to maintain. I see that your JScrollPane's bounds have a negative height and am unfamiliar with that. What's the rationale behind that?

Comment: I didnt do that. Maybe it was just windowBuilder.. so that was my main error... i believe

Comment: Just one more question... how can I use a variable that is outside a loop/a try/catch statement inside it?

Comment: Declare it *before* the loop or blocks where you want to use it.