# Use external variables inside loop/try/catch java

Tags: java

Let's supose we have:

```
final JList list = new JList(buffer.toArray());
```

I want to declare a JList as that, but I get the buffer variable from a SQL query, so, in a try loop. Is there any way to use a variable declared outside a try/catch inside it?

Answer (score 2):

Again, declare it *before* the loop or block as I noted in your [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441963/jlist-not-showing-on-jscrollpane).

Answer (score 1):

By declaring the variable outside of the try block, like this:

```
JList list = null;
try {
    list = new JList(buffer.toArray());
} catch (SomeNastyException eekwhatthebleepwentwrong) {
    // at least print some info about the exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are after:

```
JList list = null;
try {
    ...
    list = new JList(buffer.toArray());
    final JList finalist = list;
    ... instantiate anonymous class that refers to finalist
} finally {
    if (list != null) {
        ....
    }
}
```

or if the `final` has to be final outside if the try/catch/finally ...

```
JList list = null;
try {
    ...
    list = new JList(buffer.toArray());
} finally {
    if (list != null) {
        ....
    }
}
final JList finalist = list;
```

The `final` only complicates things slightly here, but the "trick" of creating a local final with the same value as a non-final is sufficient to deal with it.

(And if the `final` modifier is not required for this reason, get rid of it.  It is just causing problems.)